# MonoTouch's Soft Debugger don't connect to App on iPhone - why?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm quite new on MonoTouch, so please forgive me my question in doubt... ;-)

I need help with the soft-debugger, because it's not connecting to the App on the device. While with iPhone Simulator everything is working as expected, the following happens when I start debugging against my device:

- The is uploaded and installed to the device.
- MonoDevelop comes up with a window saying the following: "Waiting for debugger to connect on 127.0.0.1:10000..." Please start the application on the device"
- When starting the app on the device, the device vibrates indicating that the debugger is not connected....

In the settings of my App on the iPhone I have set the IP-Adress to my Mac's IP.

My iPhone is connected via WIFI to my network. I can ping my Mac from my iPhone and vice versa.

In several screenshots where the debugger was obviously working I saw that the debugger came up with the Mac's IP address and not the 127.0.0.1....

Do I have to configure my IP-address somewhere in MonoDevelop?

BTW: I'm using the latest version of MonoDevelop - it's 2.4.1

I have tried anything.... re-installing MonoDevelop, cleaning up the project several times, setting up a new project.... nothing...

Please, please help....

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoTouch debugger never connects to app.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821133/monotouch-debugger-never-connects-to-app)

Comment: Also, if you have not yet done so - delete the app from your device and try again.

Answer (score 2):

1.- Make sure you are connected the same wifi network both on device and computer

2.- Open monodevelop and your project and on top of the window select on the combobox "Debug|iPhone" [(ScreenShot)](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7792/screenshot20110117at550v.png) setting and then clic on Run(menu)->Run Option (wait until it finishes to load your app on the device and DO NOT Open it yet)

3.- Get the ip address of your computer

4.- On the iDevice make sure that the application its closed then go to Settings -> (YourAppName) here you will be with the debug settings

5.- On Debugger Host setting you must put you computers ip address

6.- on MonoDevelop under Run(menu)->Debug you will be presented with the "Waitting for Debugger"

7.- Open you application and debbuger should connect now

Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

many thanks for your replies! They were very helpful to me (especially point 5).

I have solved the problem by setting the Host IP in the ~/.config/MonoDevelop/MonoDevelopProperties.xml. That did it! :-)

Now I'm wondering where I do this setting in the MonoDevelop GUI... ;-)

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: woow nice one :) AFAIK there is no MD option to modify it, its supposed to be guessed by the environment but this is a really useful question/answer and many thanks for pointing this out. Good luck with your development and enjoy MonoTouch. Alex