# MonoDevelop iPhone simulator exits on load when running in debug, issue appears to be tied to one content file

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I run my iOS project in MonoDevelop through the simulator I get the following application output:

> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException:
>   Exception of type
>   'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException'
>   was thrown.   at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive
>   (CommandSet command_set, Int32
>   command,
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.PacketWriter
>   packet) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Type_GetInfo
>   (Int64 id) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.GetInfo
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.get_FullName
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent
>   (Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event e, Boolean
>   dequeuing) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent
>   (Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event e) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler
>   () [0x00000] in :0

Followed by the app exiting.

There's some .pngs which i copy over into the application. If I take one png and under its properties if I toggle between 'Copy Always' and 'Copy if Newer' in its 'copy to output directory' field then do a full rebuild the app runs fine. But after I stop running the simulator and try again it quits with the same issue and I have to again toggle the field and reibuild the app.

This is really strange to me, does anyone know how to fix this so I don't have to keep doing this obscure thing to get the app running?

This issue only happens when in debug mode.

edit: here's the actual application output:

> Thread started: 
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException:
>   Exception of type
>   'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException'
>   was thrown.   at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive
>   (CommandSet command_set, Int32
>   command,
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.PacketWriter
>   packet) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Type_GetInfo
>   (Int64 id) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.GetInfo
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.get_FullName
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent
>   (Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event e, Boolean
>   dequeuing) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent
>   (Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event e) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler
>   () [0x00000] in :0

I also found that if I make the game update at 30fps instead of 60fps this issue happens far less frequently..

Comment: This isn't your application output, it's the debugger disconnecting because the app crashed in native code. Take a look at the "Application Output" pad - hopefully the native crash trace will be shown there. Also, note that *Copy to Output Directory* has absolutely no effect on MonoTouch apps, it's probably the rebuild that helps.

Comment: @mhutch just added the actual application output...

Comment: That's still not the actual application output. If MD isn't returning it for some reason, check in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter (Console.app is useful for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restaring OSX and clearing out the simulator seems to have done the trick. I'm still not sure what was causing it to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue if I added the images into a "Resources" file, try renaming the pngs that you use.  The way I made it work is to load all the images as "Content" in "Build Actions" and by specifying complete paths for every instance.

Once I fixed the issue with all my images being stored in a Resources file, my simulator worked again.  If none of this works, I'd select the iOS simulator itself and try "Reset Content and Settings" and then debug your app once again.

This thread might prove helpful 
[MonoTouch debugger never connects to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821133/monotouch-debugger-never-connects-to-app)

Comment: The next version of MonoDevelop prevents putting files in a folder called *Resources* or any other iOS reserved name.

Comment: That would help a lot!  Also, will there be features for interface builder to be better integrated (pictures you insert will show up in it)?